# Creating new geometry per frame

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a node group that calculates a Trefoil knot segment based on the current frame, and I am instantiating points at the ends of this segment in each frame. This works fine. However, in the following frame, these points disappear and only points created in the current frame are visible.

Can I create additional permanent points/geometry in each frame using Geometry Nodes?

====== Update ===
[image]

I used [Chris](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/86978/chris)' (who has deleted his comments and his wrong answer) suggestion but it still only shows a segment calculated in the current frame.

[Blend file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlMTW-hoOVO59yFj0adeSDPgWIEe?e=IbBXU2)

Comment: custom nodes simply calculate the beginning and the end of the segment depending on the frame number.

Comment: GN don't hold a reference to what happened in the previous frame and don't know what will happen in the next one. One solution I see is to use a script that will create a new object for each frame using the evaluated GN modifier at that frame

Comment: Sorry but is not added if you have one and add one in another frame you should have two and this is not the case. Still it does not matter if it is a single point or a line with two points the geometry from the previous frame does not persist in the future frames. and if you read my actual question, this is what I asked about: `Can I create additional permanent points/geometry in each frame using Geometry Nodes?`

Comment: Unless you apply the modifier after each frame or create a new object like I suggested the answer is no

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The coordinates of points on a trefoil knot can be expressed parametrically, as [functions of `t`.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trefoil_knot)

`t` is 0 at the beginning of the curve, and `2*pi` at the end.

If you start your GeoNode tree like this, you initially construct a straight vertical line from the origin, which will grow from `0` to `2*pi` units high at `Frames` frames, divided into `Segments` segments:

[image]

`t` is encoded in `pz`, the Z coordinates of the points in the line.

`pz` is an attribute,(equivalent to `t`), and can be used to calculate  `x(t)`,`y(t)`,and `z(t)`. Those values can be substituted into the `position` attribute of the vertical line's vertices at the end of the tree, forming the knot incrementally, as the original vertical line grows with the number of frames.

[image]

Which gets you as far as this:

[image]

[image]

Blender 3.0a

Comment: Perfect. that's what I needed. Thank you.